# Using Bootstrap 3 radio buttons don't show well on IE11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, radio-button

In IE 10 and 11 the radio buttons overlap the text next to the button.

The html-code is as follows:

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-10" for="member_no_photo-0">
        <input type="radio" name="member_no_photo" id="member_no_photo-0" value="0" class="form-control">&nbsp; Ja
    </label>
    <label class="radio col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-10" for="member_no_photo-1">
        <input type="radio" name="member_no_photo" id="member_no_photo-1" value="1" checked="checked" class="form-control">&nbsp; Nee
    </label>
</div>
```

In other browsers than IE the radio buttons show correctly like:
http://www.miocrates.com/images/Schermafbeelding%202016-03-22%20om%2011.07.08.png

On IE 10 and 11 they show like this (I've made the radio-button background transparant to even see the label text.)

http://www.miocrates.com/images/Schermafbeelding%202016-03-22%20om%2011.06.51.png

What can be the case here?

Comment: We solved the problem. The HTML was not correct and the classes were not on the right html-tags as well. Thing look fine now.

Comment: i have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822079/bootstrap-3-radio-button-broke-ie
help me how to solved this plz