# bootstrap 3 radio button broke IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <input type="radio" name="selectDate" id="date" style="margin-right: 0" checked>Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My radio button display normal with chrome, edge, ff, but in old IE its broken - button and label not close together.

[image]

I try to use jsfiddle but radio not display when I use IE.
plz help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLvop1ws/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "control-label" class and allign 
Working code:

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left:10%">
                <input type="radio" name="selectDate" id="date" style="margin-right: 0" checked>Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
            </div>
            <div style="float:left">:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Check box and Radio button in `form-group` class. Here i wrote it again. Please use this and tell me again your issue..

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <input type="radio" name="selectDate" id="date" style="margin-right: 0" checked>Date</label>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
          </div>
          <div style="float:left">:</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thx for your help but it's not work, radio button just move to right a litte in IE, chrome, ff still no problem

Comment: @dev520 What is your IE version? 8 or 9??

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this one. I edit it

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="radio">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="selectDate" id="date" style="margin-right: 0" checked>Date
      </label>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      :
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @dev520 I remove the your radio button label `col-sm-2` and add `form-inline` class. you don't need to use for this colon ` : ` to div.

Comment: oh it work, but i need col-sm-2 to allign my from, what should i do

Comment: @dev520 ok then you have to put `col-sm-2` div class before `form-inline` class (and don't forget vote for me)